# How to validate a field only if another has been filled out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

How would I  validate a field only if another has been filled out In Ruby on Rails 2.3.5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of :address, :if => :city?

end
```

`:address` and `:city` are both attributes of `Model`.

Comment: That works! Thank you. I ended up needing to specify a proc. See my answer for the three different things the `if` attribute accepts.

Answer (score 6):

`validates_presence_of` accepts an `if` attribute that take one of three things, according to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M002164): a string, a method, or a proc.

```
if - Specifies a method, proc or string to call to determine if the validation
should occur (e.g. :if => :allow_validation, or
:if => Proc.new { |user| user.signup_step > 2 }).
The method, proc or string should return or evaluate to a true or false value.
```

I ended up needing to use a proc, as I wanted to make sure that a certain parameter was filled out before validating:

```
  validates_presence_of :bar, :if => Proc.new { |foo| !foo.age.blank? }
```

Comment: Instead of creating and answer, I suggest to edit your original question.

Comment: Thanks! This is what i was looking for!